# incorrect value outputting from while loop

Tags: python, output

Here is my code, why is 0 outputting instead of entered value?

```
cube = 0
value = int(input("Enter a value to be cubed or 0 to quit: "))

while value != 0:
    cube = value **3
    value = int(input("Enter a value to be cubed or 0 to quit: "))

print (value, "cubed is", cube)
```

Comment: because you don't print until you exit the loop.  Rearrange your statements to print in the loop after calculating.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First thing you want to do is indent that `print`, so that it refers to the values inside the loop:

```
cube = 0
value = int(input("Enter a value to be cubed or 0 to quit: "))

while value != 0:
    cube = value **3
    value = int(input("Enter a value to be cubed or 0 to quit: "))
    print (value, "cubed is", cube)
```

But now every time you print the result, `cube` refers to the previous round. So you want to change the order:

```
# no need to do cube = 0, it contributes nothing
value = int(input("Enter a value to be cubed or 0 to quit: "))

while value != 0:
    cube = value**3
    print (value, "cubed is", cube)
    value = int(input("Enter a value to be cubed or 0 to quit: "))
```

Comment: Ahhh ok that makes sense, thank you for explaining where my mistake was.